# VB macro only moves half of my read e-mails

Tags: vba, email, outlook

I have a macro in  myOutlook, which moves the read mails from Inbox to the folder called "Read". Here is the code:

```
    Private Sub no_Click()
    Unload Me
End Sub

Private Sub yes_Click()
    On Error Resume Next
        Set oOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
        Set oNameSpace = oOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
        Set oFolderSrc = oNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
        Set oFolderDst = oFolderSrc.Folders("Read")
        Set oFilteredItems = oFolderSrc.Items.Restrict("[UnRead] = False")
                For Each oMessage In oFilteredItems
                    oMessage.Move oFolderDst
                Next
End Sub
```

But, when I run the macro, it only copies half of my mails. Example: I have 500 mails in my Inbox. When I run the macro, it leaves 250 mails in my Inbox. When I run it again, it leaves 125 mails, et cetera et cetera.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Can you remove `On Error Resume Next` and see if you're getting an error?

Comment: Tried this, but no error message is displayed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
For index = oFilteredItems.Count to 1 Step -1
    oFilteredItems.Item(index).Move oFolderDst
Next
```

I suspect that the item being moved is messing up the `For Each`

Comment: Changed the For Each in my macro with the code provided above, and it works now! Thanks man!

Comment: You're welcome. When deleting or removing items from a collection -- or even moving things around in a collection -- it's better to use an indexed loop rather than `For Each`. It gives you more control over what you're doing.